# Create negative examples in dataset with only positive ones

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

Imagine we have a classification problem on a dataset where the examples are only positive (equivalently negative). For instance, on a problem where the the winning class is specified by position (e.g. think of a tennis dataset problem where the first player is always the winner). How can we create negative examples in order to train a supervised learning algorithm on this dataset? One idea could be to generate negative examples, by exchanging the positions of the features that are tied to each of the classes. Do you think this will give an unbiased dataset? Could we create negative duplicates of our original dataset and train a supervised learning algorithm on this double dataset?